# swagger url for WSO2 Governance registry5.4.0 REST API

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I am exploring the WSO2 Governance registry version 5.4.0. I would like to get the swagger url for WSO2 governance registry REST API so that I can call the rest apis to create/update/delete/get resources in Publisher portal.
I have installed the WSO2 Governance registry 5.4.0 locally on my windows 10 machine.

Please help me with this. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is not a programming issue but support. Please refer below documentations provided by WSO2:

- [Invoking a REST Service Using the In-built Swagger UI](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance540/Invoking+a+REST+Service+Using+the+In-built+Swagger+UI)
- [Adding a
  REST Service](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance540/Adding+a+REST+Service)

For this case you better subscribe to [WSO2 mailing list](https://wso2.com/mail/) and mail them your query. They will surely reach you.